# Who are the nations and where do they come from in Revelation 20:7-8?

Tags: revelation, prophecy, referent-identification, eschatology, john-the-revelator

Revelation 20:7-8 NASB

> 7 When the thousand years are completed, Satan will be released from his prison, 8 and will come out to ***deceive the nations*** which are at the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, to gather them together for the war; the number of them is like the sand of the [c]seashore.

Im a little bit mixed up about these nations who will be deceived by Satan and which will surround the saints and the beloved city.

Who and where do this nations come from?

Comment: They are already on the earth. They are all around us. They are the world which is deceived by the Wicked One. Is that not clear throughout the Apocalypse ?

Comment: @NigelJ-Just read one comment which stated that these are the ones that are resurrected at the close of the millennium

Comment: I see (very plainly) that Revelation is in seven sections which view the Church Age from different aspects. So that view does not concur with what I see. The idea of Christ returning to (this) earth and establishing a kingdom on (this present) earth contradicts all I know of Christ and his gospel.  Jesus Christ will never again set foot on this earth : it is to be judged and to be destroyed. Else, why did he leave it in the first place ? ? ?

Comment: @NigelJ. That is incorrect, It is written in multiple places, Christ will rule from Zion on Earth. When he returns he has a lot of work to do, to establish righteousness, Justice and Judgment, and to make Jerusalem a praise in all the earth. He'll rule with an iron rod, and will give mercy to the nations, but if they don't conform then they will meet their end. Nations become tributaries to the kingdom.

Comment: @collenndhlovu The nations in Rev20:7-8 are the survivors of the wrath that is poured out on all nations. Those who went against Jerusalem. Zec14:16. But its written in many places.

Answer (score 2):

In Rev 20 we have two sets of people in view, the righteous/faithful saints and the wicked.  This question concerns the wicked.

- V5: The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were ended.

The NT discusses two resurrections - one of the righteous and other of the wicked, John 5:28, 29, Dan 12:2, Acts 24:15, Heb 11:35.  See also Rev 1:7.

The resurrection of the wicked, according to Rev 20:5, occurs at the end of the 1000 years and Satan goes our to deceive them again. - to surround and the Holy City, the New Jerusalem -

> **9** ... But fire came down from heaven and devoured them. **10** And the devil, who deceived them, was thrown into the lake of burning
> sulfur, where the beast and the false prophet had been thrown. ...

"Gog and Magog" is a reference to the same names in Eze 38 & 39.  Gog of Magog attack God's people and the resurrected wicked after the 1000 are stirred up by Satan to do the same and thus are compared to the huge army in the prophecy of Eze 38 & 39.

Comment: Thats not quite right, if they are already condemned Satan doesn't need to deceive them again. Satan is deceiving the nations that have dwelt on the earth through out the 1000 year reign. it's written in many places throughout the TaNaK.

Comment: It is the Sacred scriptures. The TaNaK is an acronym representing the old testament. It consists of the Torah, Nevi'im and Ketuvim.